# Does Google Search exclude contents of <nav> from summary?

Tags: google-search, html5

HTML5 has a new tag, `<nav>`.

Do popular search-engines ignore contents within such tag when they generate page summaries?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, Google will not differentiate the tags as whatever they see in view source, they will consider them while indexing the page.

I did some search on Google and found this interesting discussion on Google product group. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/NvB9f5n0saU

This post is bit old but you can find the solution you are looking for.